# RethinkDB: order / index by version - build

Tags: rethinkdb

I have records with the following field: `{ version: "2.4.1-5dev" }`. I want to order / index them by version. The documents should be ordered by the version / build combination (ascending by their partially-numeric values). Is it possible, and if so, how can I do that?

edit:

I still can't index/order by version. Again, I want to be able to sort by version, *even* if there are words like "dev" in them.

In python, there's `pkg_resources.parse_version()` which helps compare two versions by `pkg_resources.parse_version(ver1) > pkg_resources.parse_version(ver2)` and it works even for somewhat crazy version naming.

Is there any chance I can use pkg_resources.parse_version() as a cmp function for indexing / ordering, or alternatively, get the same result within a query when trying to order documents by the version field?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index with a function, in JavaScript it would be something like

```
r.table("product").indexCreate("version", function(product) {
    return r.branch(
        product("version").match('dev'),
        null,
        product("version").split('.').concatMap(function(version) {
            return version.split('-')
        }).map(function(num) {
            return num.coerceTo('NUMBER')
        })
})
```

That works because `null` is currently not stored in secondary indexes, this behavior may change though -- See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1032

The third argument in r.branch, split the value on `.` and `-` then coerce each value to a number. For example

```
r.expr("2.4.1-5").split('.').concatMap(r.row.split('-')).map(r.row.coerceTo('NUMBER'))
// will return [2,4,1,5]
```

Comment: Two things: 1) I'm getting an exception saying 'Cannot use r.row in nested queries', 2) for example, in javascript [2, 4, 1, 5] < [2, 4, 1, 11] is false (which is not good) unlike python where this kind of comparisons gives the wanted result (if I understand your intentions correctly)

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to that. I just edited the query, it should work fine now.

Comment: Still can't figure out how to do it. I tried to play with your solution, and still, the result is not ordered correctly... Please check question edit